# Freebsd 10 install with non standard gateway route

Tags: routing, vps, freebsd, dedicated-server, static-routes

Some service providers offer dedicated/vps nodes with non standard gateways (ie not in the same subnet).

For instance : ip add 10.0.1.1/32 with gateway 56.0.1.1 
For this purpose some manual steps are required since the install wizard does not accept gateways outside the main ip's subnet.

Especially something like this :

```
   route add 56.0.1.1 10.0.1.1
   route add default 56.0.1.1
   echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
   ping google.com (working now)
```

The problem is that regardless of functionality up to this point, when you exit the install shell or you run bsdinstall from the live environment the settings are lost and the install fails to download from various ftp mirrors.

How do i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The penultimate step in `bsdinstall` asks if you would like to open a shell to make manual modifications. At this point, you could edit either `/etc/rc.conf` and add some suitable directives or add an `/etc/rc.local` with the commands listed in your question.

I tested an *Auto (UFS)* and an *Auto (ZFS)* install and both times the newly created `rc.conf` file was writable at:

```
vi /etc/rc.conf
```

Comment: Yes good point but it doesn't work. complains the file is read only and it is since it's the mounted iso.

Comment: @Horatiu I have updated my answer.